# Does PHP have a function to detect the OS it's running on?

Tags: php, operating-system, newline

I wouldn't know under what keyword to look for this in the PHP database, so I'm asking here.

Reason I want to know is because of how different Operating Systems handle new lines in textdocuments.

I'm using a CSV file in windows but each time I think I add a new line, what really happens is the new line gets pasted to the back of the latest line.

Reason is, in windows, a new line is this: `\r\n`
And the CSVHandler.class.php file I'm using only adds `\n`

However, in MAC OS X that's the new line, which is different from windows.

So I'm looking for this so I can implement a simple `if()` statement and solve this. Currently I've hardcoded the `\r\n`, but it should be simpler, no?

Comment: yeah, it's \r\n on win, \n on *nix and \r on mac (that's the most stupid implementation from the three)

Comment: Now that Macs are FreeBSD-based, don't they use \n as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP has included the constant [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for solving the problem you face, available since php 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2 - it contains a suitable end-of-line sequence for the server that PHP is running on.

If you want to use a different end-of-line sequence suitable for a particular client, then you'll have to code that yourself. One way to determine the client OS is to use [get_browser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), assuming your server has an up-to-date [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp)

Answer (score 12):

You could use the predefined constant **PHP_OS**.

I'm using

> if (PHP_OS === 'WINNT') {...}

Answer (score 6):

The information about the server operating system can be obtained with `php_uname()` function:

```
echo 'I have been run on '.php_uname('s');
```

It also allows to retrieve the full information on the version.

Comment: Helped me out with a similar question. +1

Answer (score 2):

Check the $_SERVER variable.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
```

You can then use strstr (or any string comparison function) to check if you are on Windows. In this example, I checked the SERVER_SIGNATURE but you can use whatever key you want.

```
$isWindows = strstr($_SERVER[SERVER_SIGNATURE], "Win32") !== FALSE;
```

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'] was empty on my Windows machine (Apache 2.2 running PHP 5.3 on Windows 7 64 bits). I used another $_SERVER variable:


    $isWindows = strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win32") ? true : false;

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to do a php info call to have a look at a lot of the configuration settings on your PHP setup, code is simple:

```
phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if PHP is running on Windows, there will be an environment variable named WINDIR. I think that you could do this:

```
$isWindows = isset($_SERVER['WINDIR']);
```

Comment: An ugly workaround that should work. But a more elegant solution must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers aleady, but here is my 2cents:

```
function windows_server()
#   Purpose:    Check if server is Windows
{
    return in_array(strtolower(PHP_OS), array("win32", "windows", "winnt"));
}

## --------------------------------------------------------

function linux_server()
#   Purpose:    Check if server is Linux
{
    return in_array(strtolower(PHP_OS), array("linux", "superior operating system"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [php_uname](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php).  Just read the explanation from the docs:

> php_uname — Returns information about the operating system PHP is
>   running on

I did like the suggestion of **PHP_OS** above, but be careful, per this note from the docs:

> consider using the PHP_OS constant, but keep in mind this constant
>   will contain the operating system PHP was ***built*** on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the safest thing to do when reading is to determine the line ending character(s) from the file itself, or accept all line endings interchangeably. This protects you from harm if you copy the csv file from one machine to another with a different OS. If you read before writing, you can make your output line endings match the line endings you identified when reading.

For CSV files, php has some library functions. Try searching php.net for fgetcsv and fputcsv. There is the auto_detect_line_endings which can be set in the php.ini, but I don't know the specifics of how it works.

I always use the "\n" by itself on both linux and windows. I use notepad to edit them in windows and it doesn't break the endings. For my own use of csv I find that it's too much hassle to support different endings, but if it's something users have to interact with then you want to be safe rather than convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$OSList = array
(
        // Match user agent string with operating systems
        'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
        'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)',
        'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
        'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
        'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
        'Windows Server 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
        'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)',
        'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 7.0)',
        'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
        'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
        'Open BSD' => 'OpenBSD',
        'Sun OS' => 'SunOS',
        'Linux' => '(Linux)|(X11)',
        'Mac OS' => '(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
        'QNX' => 'QNX',
        'BeOS' => 'BeOS',
        'OS/2' => 'OS/2',
        'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
);

// Loop through the array of user agents and matching operating systems
foreach($OSList as $CurrOS=>$Match)
{
        // Find a match
        if (eregi($Match, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
                // We found the correct match
                break;
        }
}
// You are using Windows Vista
echo "You are using ".$CurrOS;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$svr_os=strtolower(reset(explode(' ',php_uname('s'))));

$isLinux=$svr_os==='linux';

$isWindows=$svr_os==='windows';
```