# Adapter pattern with static classes

Tags: php, adapter, static-classes

I am looking for a good way to implement the Adaptor pattern with static classes in PHP 5.x.

One of the examples where I would like to use this, is as a counterpart to Python's `os.path.join()`.
I would have two adaptees, a Windows and a Linux adaptee class.

I think it is reasonable, to implement these classes as static classes, because they have no "context". They do not need to store any state and creating an instance everytime I need one seems superfluous - therefore I am looking for a clean way to implement this.

Let's consider the following bogus implementation:

```
    static public function join(){
        $parts = func_get_args();
        $joined = array(MY_MAGICALLY_PASSED_DEFAULT_PATH_PREFIX);
        foreach($parts as $part){
            $part = self::$adaptee->cleanPath($path);
            if(self::$adaptee->isAbsolute($part)){
                $joined = array($part);
            }
            else{
                $joined[] = $part;
            }
        }
        return implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $joined);
    }
```

The first thing you will notice is, that it assumes an initialized static member called adaptee which would hold the necessary, OS-dependent implementation details.

This requires me to have an arbitrarily named static constructor-like function, that I would call immediately after the declaration of the class. (Another thing that bothers me with this approach).

Of course, I could initialize a local `$adaptee` variable on each method call, but that seems like inappropriate and I would have to  replicate that in each other static function that needs the adaptee.

Now... for PHP's class implemention detail: They are not first-class objects, so I couldn't just pass the class as an argument. In the example, it requires me to create the Adaptees as *non-static* (what is the term for this?) classes, then instantiate it and eventually assign it to the static `$adaptee` member variable of the Adapter class.

Maybe this is just this weird and completely subjective thought that I have... but I really feel that it is not appropriate to do it like this. Do you have any ideas about a better implementation?

One other idea that I've had is, to store the adaptee's class name instead, and use `call_user_func` instead, but I don't feel too comfortable using this approach.

## Update

I may not have described this properly, so I will try to explain this in an update:

I am not looking on how to get the underlying Operating System, but I would like to have a neat way, for a static class to act differently depending on whether the OS is Linux, Windows, FreeBSD or something else.

I thought of the adaptor pattern, but since I don't have a static constructor, I cannot really initialize the class. One way would be to initialize it at the beginning of every public static method call (or just check whether it is initialized).

The other possibility would be, to create a static constructor-like method and simply call it right after the declaration. That might do the trick, but I am just wondering what other, possibly more elgeant methods there are, to achieving this.

As for my initial example:
It is supposed to be a utility function, it does not need to preserve state in any kind really, so I am not looking for a Path-Object of any sorts. What I would like, is a Path factory function, that returns a string, without having to differentiate between the different OSes every time when called. The "library"-thing led me to create a static class as pseudo-namespace for my related utility functions, and the different implementation details that need to be supported to the adaptor pattern. Now I am looking for an elegant way, to combine the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll shoot yourself in the foot when you make them static. You cannot inject static classes so you will always have coupling to the global scope and because you will hardcode static calls everywhere, maintaining them will become a nightmare. And you cannot mock them either (ok, PHPUnit can, but it only does to enable testing of code that otherwise would be untestable).

Just create an instance and use regular functions and save yourself some worries. There is no advantage in using statics. And the performance impact is utterly and totally negligible.

I'd probably create an interface for the adaptee and the adapters to implement

```
interface IPathAdapter
{
    public function cleanPath($path);
    public function isAbsolutePath($part);
    // more …
}
```

and then do probably something like

```
class Path implements IPathAdapter
{
    protected $_adapter;

    public function __construct(IPathAdapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->_adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function cleanPath($path)
    {
        $this->_adapter->cleanPath($part);
    }

    public function isAbsolutePath($part)
    {
        $this->_adapter->isAbsolutePath($part);
    }

    // more …

    public function join(){
        $parts = func_get_args();
        $joined = array($this->getScriptPath());
        foreach($parts as $part){
            $part = $this->cleanPath($path);
            if ($this->isAbsolutePath($part)){
                $joined = array($part);
            } else{
                $joined[] = $part;
            }
        }
        return implode($this->getPathSeparator(), $joined);
    }
}
```

So when I want to use Path, I'd have to do

```
$path = new Path(new PathAdapter_Windows);
```

If you cannot inject the adapters, I'd probably go the route you already suggested and pass the Adapter class name as an argument to instantiate it from within Path then. Or I'd leave the detection of the appropriate adapter completely to the Path class, e.g. have it detect the OS and then instantiate what is needed.

If you want to autodetect, have a look at [Does PHP have a function to detect the OS it's running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623776/does-php-have-a-function-to-detect-the-os-its-running-on). I'd probably write a separate class to handle the identification and then make it a dependency to the Path class, e.g.

```
public function __construct(IDetector $detector = NULL)
{
    if($detector === NULL){
        $detector = new OSDetector;
    }
    $this->_detector = $detector; 
}
```

The reason I am injecting is because it will allow me to change the implementation, e.g. to mock the Detector in UnitTests but can also ignore to inject at runtime. It will use the default OSDetector then. With the detector, detect the OS and create an appropriate adapter somewhere in Path or in a dedicated Factory.

Comment: Do you mean for the both adaptor and adaptees, or are you refering solely to adaptees? I wouldn't want to make them static really, because I cannot see a reasonable implementation really. The adaptor however, is meant to be more of a pseudo-namespace to provide some library/utility functions. Also I don't like the idea of having to instantiate it every time I want to use it (I could use a factory instead I guess)

Comment: (leaving my initial comment for completeness' sake) - Ok I can see what you mean. I agree with you, that your approach makes perfect sense for most adaptor/adaptee cases, but I in this example when it is about wrapping OS dependent functionality, I feel that manually injecting the adaptor and defining an interface for the adaptor is overkill in this particular case. My intention is, to have the caller not care about the implementation details, hence injecting the Adaptee is not appropriate, there is going to be two, maybe thee possibilities: Linux/Unix(Mac) and Windows.

Comment: @phant0m well, like I said, I'd pass in a string in that case, though I don't see much of a difference between passing a string and passing an instance, except that you can defer instantiation of the adapter when you pass the string. Adapters in Zend Framework use this approach a lot. You might want to have a look their sourcecode. If you want to hide everything away from the client, try to autodetect the OS.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about that, passing a string instead is virtually the same thing. Maybe I haven't made the use of this class clear enough: It will be used to deal with paths internally which will always be dependant on the implementation on which PHP will be run, not with client code in that sense. So autodetecting would be my choice - I was just wondering why you presentend your example in this fashion, and was wondering what the deeper sense is behind this method.

Comment: @phant0m The only reason I presented it this way is because I think it's the cleanest solution. I'm curious. PHP already does a good job handling pathes independent from the OS. What are the issues you face? If you want to autodetect, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623776/does-php-have-a-function-to-detect-the-os-its-running-on. PHP has a constant PHP_OS that you could try for this. I'd probably create a class OSDetector for this though to keep the responsibility where it belongs.

Comment: The best reference you can find really, is Python's os.path.join. The idea is, that it will automatically concatenate paths for you, and you do not have to worry about missing path seperators in between. The arguments are processed sequentially - if an absolute path is encountered, the previous arguments will be disgarded.
This makes the following syntax possible: Path::join($default, $relative_path, $relative_partial_path2);
Also, you could override the default location by passing an absolute path instead. Eventually, it is a factory method to create a definite path,hence the static approach.

Comment: @phant0m well, dont know what else to tell you. I understood you are facing two problems: instantiation of the correct adapter and getting the proper OS dependent values from it. For instantiation, you've got the options shown above. For getting the values, add small discrete methods to the adapter and then call these within your class. If this is not what you are looking for, I might not be getting the issue then. Sorry for that.

Comment: We do seem to be talking a little at cross purposes here. I'm not looking at how to detect the OS or something like that, for that I could consult the manual :) - What I wanted to have, was something like this: `$path_string = Path::join(arg1, arg2 etc)`. W/o using a "static constructor", there seems to be little alternative. But thinking about it, I might also create a path class with context and state, instead of a library with path-related functionality. Because the latter seems to be more flexible really, it is also closer to your answer.

Comment: Although it's not exactly what I was looking for, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for the time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, you just have to put the namespace path into a global var, for example in composer autoload.php:

$GLOBALS['ADAPTED_CLASS_NAMESPACE'] = 'MyComponent\AdapterFoo\VendorBar';

I think it's a good approach in a context where you can't use dependency injection i.e in a entity for validation (we keep in mind that separated Validation classes are better).

```
<?php

namespace MyComponent;

use MyComponent\AdaptedInterface;
use ReflectionClass;

class Adapter
{
    /**
     * @var AdaptedInterface
     */
    protected $adaptedClass;

    public function __construct(AdaptedInterface $validator = null)
    {
        if (null == $validator && $this->validateClassPath($GLOBALS['ADAPTED_CLASS_NAMESPACE'])) {
            $this->adaptedClass = new $GLOBALS['ADAPTED_CLASS_NAMESPACE'];
        } else {
            $this->adaptedClass = $validator;
        }
    }

    protected function validateClassPath($classPath)
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($classPath);

        if (!$reflection->implementsInterface(
            'MyComponent\AdaptedInterface'
        )) {
            throw new \Exception('Your adapted class have not a valid class path :' . $classPath . 'given');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So anywhere:

```
(new Adapter())->foo($bar);
```